# Completeness of Algebraically Closed Valued Fields(ACVF) Theory

Tags: model-theory, valuation-theory, lo.logic

One can prove Elimination of Quantifiers of ACVF finding an extension of any partial embedding of a model $K$ into a $|K|^+$ Saturated one using the language $\mathcal{L} = ( 0,1,+,*, U, \mid )$. In this Language $U$ is the unary predicate standing for the Valuation Ring of the model, and $\mid $ is a binary relation such that $x\mid y \leftrightarrow \exists z\in U \ x*z=y$.  How do you prove the completeness of this theory in that language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like with algebraically closed fields, for completeness you need to specify the characteristic of the field and the characteristic of the residue field.

There is a general trick if you have a theory $T$ with quantifier elimination and a structure $A$ that is embedded in every model of $T$, then $T$ is complete.  Let $M$ and $N$ be models of $T$ and let $\phi$ be any sentence.  There is a quantifier free sentence $\psi$
that is equivalent to $\phi$ in models of $T$.  But, since $\psi$ is quantifier free,
$$M\models \psi\Leftrightarrow A\models\psi\Leftrightarrow N \models\psi.$$ Thus
$M\models\phi\Leftrightarrow N\models \phi$.

Now, suppose you are looking at characteristic 0 fields with characteristic p residue field.  The rationals with the p-adic valuation are a substructure of any model of ACVF of characteristic $0$ with characteristic $p$ residue field.